# Difficulty understanding javascript array of anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently having trouble understanding the following Javascript code and after searching a bit I still cannot figure it out. I've included the function below

```
function buildFunctions(){

    var arr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        arr.push(function(){
            console.log(i);
        })
    }

    return arr;
}


var fs = buildFunctions();

fs[0]();
fs[1]();
fs[2]();
```

**Question: Can someone please help me understand why the following code produces all 3's instead of 0, 1, 2?**

I'd really like to understand exactly what's going on here, but I don't see why the functions doesn't output 0, 1, 2

Comment: Can you post raw code?

Comment: I would suggest reading about javascript closures.  In this example, each `i` is a reference back to the scope in which the anonymous function is created.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: I've edited my question and I'll make sure to post code next time, sorry about that. Also, thanks for the linked to question!! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks